# \cr extra alignment!

Tags: tables, xepersian

When I use the code below to create a table written in Persian, it gives me the following error:

> `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
>   <recently read> \endtemplate`

code:

```
      \begin{table}[h!]
            \centering
              \begin{tabular}{c  c  c  c  c  c  c} 
       \hline
        \\رتبه نهایی    &بهره‌وری&  &رتبه اثربخشی   &اثربخشی    &رتبه& کارایی&  کارایی  DMU
    \hline
  15    &56٫۷&  18&56٫۷&    1&100&1\\
  5 &74٫۹   &8  &79٫۰   &5  &94٫۸   &2\\
  1 &92٫۱   &2  &99٫۳&  6&92٫۸&3\\
  8 &63٫۵   &14 &63٫5&  1&100   &4\\
  4 &75٫۳   &6  &86٫4   &11 &87٫۱   &5\\
  14    &56٫9   &11 &67٫۱   &13 &84٫۸   &6\\
  18    &50٫۱   &17 &57٫۰   &10 &87٫۹   &7\\
  2 &87٫۱   &3  &98٫6   &9  &88٫۳   &8\\
  17    &54٫6   &10 &72٫8   &18 &75٫۰   &9\\
  3 &83٫۳   &1  &100    &14 &83٫۳   &10\\
  9 &63٫۲   &7  &83٫۳   &17 &75٫۹   &11\\
  16    &56٫4   &16 &59٫۰   &4  &95٫5   &12\\
  12    &58٫4   &13 &63٫۹   &8  &91٫4   &13\\
  7 &69٫5   &4  &90٫6   &16 &76٫۷   &14\\
  13    &57٫6   &15 &62٫۳   &7  &92٫۵   &15\\
  10    &63٫۰   &12 &64٫۹   &3  &97٫۰   &16\\
   11   &62٫۷   &9  &73٫۲   &12 &85٫۷   &17\\ 
   6    &71٫۱   &5  &89٫۵   &15 &79٫۳   &18\\

   \hline

   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please complete your example in order to make it compilable. You will get help much quicker, if you try to kick out all the Persian stuff. If this issue just appears in Persian, you should make this clear in your question. On first sight: The first row is having \\ on the left, the rest on the right. Is that correct?

Comment: you are missing `\\ ` at the end of the first row, before the `\hline`

Comment: i did but because of persian font it's in the first of the line

Comment: ah tricky thing bidi:-)

Answer (score 3):

You have not quoted the full error message which is

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.9 ...  &اثربخشی    &رتبه& کارایی&
                                                    کارایی  DMU
```

which tells you the problem is on line 9 and shows which `&` is the problem. (Always use a code section when quoting error messages as line breaks are very important in TeX errors, the break here shows the `&` which has just been read, and which triggered the error, and  that the extra cell with DMU has not yet been processed. )

You have declared 7 columns `{c  c  c  c  c  c  c}` but the first row has 7 `&` (so 8 columns)

Comment: conclusion is correct, but the quoted text doesn't agree with the original.

Comment: @barbarabeeton well I certainly didn't retype it:-) probably the encoding or directionality got mangled somewhere between cutting and pasting from the terminal error message to here.

Comment: cutting and pasting -- never very reliable, i find.  rather frustrating.